# Remove the generated modules/ext folder for a Netbeans Platform Application under Maven

Tags: maven, netbeans

I have a Netbeans Platform Application which is builded with Maven.

I would like to edit the pom.xml in order to remove the generated folder "modules/ext" (containing all external libs) before the zip generation (nbm:standalone-zip goal)

I tried this :

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <!--remove the module/ext directory-->
                <execution>
                    <id>rmExt</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>exec</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <executable>/bin/rm</executable>
                        <workingDirectory />
                        <arguments>
                            <argument>-rf</argument>
                            <argument>${project.build.directory}/myapp/myapp/modules/ext</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
</plugin>
```

I tried to change the goal but the folder is not removed and then contained in the zip.

Do you have some ideas ?

Thank you

Comment: I would ask why do you want to remove that.. the modules/ext files are likely used by one of the modules and that module will fail at runtime, missing it's wrapped libs.. So it would be better to describe the problem not the solution.

Comment: Yes, I have forgotten to talk about it.
In fact, all dependencies are given in arguments in the command line, (specific use).
These dependencies are shared between some application and are centralized, so the dependencies must no be embedded with the Netbeans Platform Application.

Comment: that would lead me to believe you need your own version of nbm-maven-plugin more or less.. that's a fairly off-the-beaten-track requirement..

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Maven 3, you may run mvn with -X and see what order the plugin executions have.  Could the zip execution be running before the `rmExt` execution?  Perhaps binding the 'rmExt` execution to an earlier phase (such as prepare-package) would help.

I suggest using the [Maven clean plugin's](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/index.html) clean goal instead of maven exec as well.  Make sure you set `excludeDefaultDirectories` to true if you make the change.